# Что значит ошибка NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview.adapter

Что значит ошибка и как ее исправить
`NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference`

Вот LogCat

`ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.example.asus.testapp.ContentAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContentAdapter.java:46)
                                                       at com.example.asus.testapp.ContentAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContentAdapter.java:12)`

Logcat указывает на
строчку 12

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

и строчку 46

```
CardFeed cardfeed = cardfeedlist.get(position);
```

Вот весть код адаптера.

```
public class ContentAdapter extends    
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CardFeed> cardfeedlist;

    public ContentAdapter(List<CardFeed> cardfeed) {
        this.cardfeedlist = cardfeed;
    }


    private static final int LENGTH = 18;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView cvUser;
        TextView cvLocation;
        ImageView cvPhoto;
        TextView cvContent;

        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_feed, parent, false));
            cvUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_user);
            cvLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_location);
            cvPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            cvContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardFeed cardfeed = cardfeedlist.get(position);
        holder.cvUser.setText(cardfeed.getName());
        holder.cvLocation.setText(cardfeed.getLocation());
        holder.cvContent.setText(cardfeed.getDescription());
        holder.cvPhoto.setImageResource(cardfeed.getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return LENGTH;
    }
}

Вот код List с items

    public class CardFeed {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String description;
    private int photo;

    public CardFeed(){

    }

    public CardFeed(String name, String location, String description, int photo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.description = description;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public int getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(int photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
```

Comment: мне нужен именно этот случай с адаптером

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep, проблемного кода нет в вопросе. У вас `cardfeedlist` `null` на момент обращения. Значит вы его таким в адаптер и передали.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хорошо, а где это изменить?

Comment: Скинул код List

Comment: код CardFeed тут вообще не причём. В том месте, где Вы создаёте адаптер смотрите. Списоку, который Вы передаёте ему в конструктор, ничего не присвоено.

Comment: Хорошо, а что и как ему надо присвоить?

Comment: А мы, по Вашему, экстрасенсы? Откуда нам знать, что Вы хотите в своём приложении показать и где и как Вы это берёте.

Answer (score 4):

В конструкторе у своего адаптера вы инициализируете свой список:

```
public ContentAdapter(List<CardFeed> cardfeed) {
    this.cardfeedlist = cardfeed;
}
```

Затем на указанной строке вы обращаетесь к нему:

```
CardFeed cardfeed = cardfeedlist.get(position);
```

Как вам правильно ответили в комментариях, в момент обращения список был равен `null`. А значит, когда вы инициализировали свой адаптер где-то в другом месте, вы передали туда вместо списка `null`.

Пройдитесь по цепочке вызовов. Как вам также правильно написали — экстрасенсов здесь нет, и узнать, что вы передаёте в конструктор адаптера при его инициализации, никто не знает.

Проверьте. Например:

```
// Здесь вы берёте откуда-то свои данные
List<CardFeed> firstList = someClass.getNecessaryData(param0, param1);

// Здесь вы устанавливаете адаптер вашему ресайклеру
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(ContentAdapter(firstList));
```

Наверняка вы делаете также? Так вот значит вам возвращается `null` там, откуда вы берёте свои данные — в моём примере это метод `getNecessaryData()`.

Гадать никто не станет, а вам просто-напросто необходимо пройтись по цепочке вызовов и узнать, где же всё-таки первый раз появляется `null`.